# Generating a Dictionary until a certain Key is Given?

Tags: python-3.x

my task is to code for a dictionary that will read in a key on one line, a value on another line (with both being strings), and will continue to read in pairs until the word "EXIT" is given for a key. My code should then print out the dictionary.

the code i have already made is here, but when i run it, the very first input is the only one treated as a value, and all others until I enter "EXIT" are treated like keys. Do you have any ways to fix this?

```
value = input()
key = input()
my_dict = {}

while key != "EXIT":
    my_dict[key] = value
    key = input()

print (my_dict)

lookup = input()

my_dict.get(lookup, "NOT FOUND")
```

Comment: You need to bring `value = input()` into your while loop

Answer (score 0):

As Nick said, you are missing each new value assignment in your loop. Something like this will resolve the issue:

```
my_dict = {}

while True:
    key = input("Please enter a key: ")
    if key == "EXIT":
        break
    my_dict[key] = input("Please enter a value: ")

print(my_dict)
```